# Correct way to add android libraries with ADT 14 >

Tags: android, eclipse

After updating to ADT 14/15 I started having a couple problems with our build.

With one Android based libraries (call it Framework) which is added into the actual android project app (call it App).  The Framework project has a couple jar files in its own lib folder which is added to its own build path.  Those same jar files are required to be added to the App's build path as well.

So jar files on the Framework build path
Framework/libs roboguice
Framework/libs gson

Those same jar files on the App build path
Framework/libs roboguice
Framework/libs gson

Also the Framework.apk is added via the Android Library panel in the App's project properties.
Both projects are targeting the same Android.

Now when I build the project I seem to have resolved the errors however when running it, at times I receive the Missing Framework.apk in the console window.

So based on this scenario any thoughts on how to correct this build?  I have a feeling its still setup incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you out!
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html

Comment: This documentation helped fix the problem I was having.  Basically I had to unlink the android library project.  In the documentation it stated to right click on android library project reference which showed up under your project with <Android Library Project Name>_src.  Right click and hit Remove from your Build Path.  This option didn't show up for me so I just clicked on this entries and hit "Delete."  At least that worked.